# SSIS Formatting Column Data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

How can i format Column Data in SSIS, similar to MSSQL

SQL: Select **FORMAT(7.326, '00.0000000')** AS 'Format'

Results: **07.3260000**

As you can see, I need both leading 0 and trailing 0 with 10 Character long with 2 before decimal "."

Thank you,

M

Comment: Is the source data column a decimal? Or what format?

Answer (score 4):

I'll do this in four steps to explain the logic. It can be done all at once, and I'll add that expression at the end, but it's a lot to try to take in all by itself. This seems like a lot, because it is, but the `FORMAT` function does a lot of work, which is why it's such a performance dog.

I'm using a column called `ColVal` (cleverly, Column Value), which I defined as `decimal(18,10)` in order to account for any numbers that might show up for you with more than the anticipated number of digits on either side of the decimal point.

**Data Type Conversion**

First off, any "number" with a leading zero is really character data. Since you're changing data types, it's probably easiest to add a column to your data flow for the results of this conversion.

For this exercise, I started with an explicit data conversion to make the rest of the expressions easier to read. For the step through, then, we'll use `ColValChar`, but, again, we'll wrap it up in the end.

**Left Of The Decimal: The Leading Zero(s)**

First, find the portion to the left.

```
LeftChar (new column) = LEFT(ColValChar,FINDSTRING(ColValChar,".",1) - 1)
```

Then add a leading zero to it if it's fewer than two characters long. Otherwise, leave it the way we found it.

```
PaddedLeft = LEN(LeftChar) < 2 ? RIGHT("00" + LeftChar,2) : LeftChar
```

**Right Of The Decimal: The Trailing Zeroes**

Find the portion of the string to the right.

```
RightChar = RIGHT(ColValChar,LEN(ColValChar) - FINDSTRING(ColValChar,".",1))
```

Pad that out, or trim it to seven, as needed.

```
PaddedRight = LEFT(RightChar + "0000000",7)
```

**Put Humpty Dumpty Together Again**

Then just stick the two strings back together.

```
SteppedColumn = PaddedLeft + "." + PaddedRight
```

When I did this, I used several intermediate tasks. It ends in a `Multicast` because I was just using data viewers to check my work.

[image]

**Doing It All In One Big, Ugly Expression**

For reasons that I don't always understand, people seem to like to build big, hard to debug expressions in SSIS. I'm not a fan, but it seems to be more the norm than the exception. With that in mind, yes, it's possible to do this all at once. Note that every single time you reference the source data, you have to convert it to character data for all of this to come together correctly.

```
BigUglyColumn = 
(LEN(LEFT((DT_STR, 30, 1252)ColVal,FINDSTRING((DT_STR, 30, 1252)ColVal,".",1) - 1)) < 2 ? 
RIGHT("00" + LEFT((DT_STR, 30, 1252)ColVal,FINDSTRING((DT_STR, 30, 1252)ColVal,".",1) - 1),2) 
: LEFT((DT_STR, 30, 1252)ColVal,FINDSTRING((DT_STR, 30, 1252)ColVal,".",1) - 1)) 
+ "." 
+ LEFT(RIGHT((DT_STR, 30, 1252)ColVal,LEN((DT_STR, 30, 1252)ColVal) - 
FINDSTRING((DT_STR, 30, 1252)ColVal,".",1)) + "0000000",7)
```

Either way will work, though. Here's the result set from my last data viewer.

```
+-------+-------------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| ColID |   ColVal    | LeftChar | RightChar | PaddedLeft | PaddedRight | SteppedColumn | BigUglyColumn |
+-------+-------------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|     1 |       2.345 |        2 |       345 |         02 |     3450000 |    02.3450000 |    02.3450000 |
|     2 |      12.346 |       12 |       346 |         12 |     3460000 |    12.3460000 |    12.3460000 |
|     3 |     112.347 |      112 |       347 |        112 |     3470000 |   112.3470000 |   112.3470000 |
|     4 |       0.348 |        0 |       348 |         00 |     3480000 |    00.3480000 |    00.3480000 |
|     5 | 3.123456789 |        3 | 123456789 |         03 |     1234567 |    03.1234567 |    03.1234567 |
+-------+-------------+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Eric which answer is very good. here is the solution using a script component:

```
string[] pieces = Row.n.ToString().Split('.');

Row.padded = ("00" + pieces[0]).Substring(("00" + pieces[0]).Length -2,2) + "."
                 + (pieces[1] + "0000000").Substring(0,7);
```

Here's a look at the data flow:

[image]

I'll add a note that there is no error handling for no decimal.